# Chicago-de.bst: change underline to italics

Tags: bibliographies, bst

I'm using a German variant of the `chicago.bst` file (source: https://github.com/MissBC/LaTeX-Vorlage-KIT-Abschlussarbeit/blob/master/chicago-de.bst) for my dissertation.

The output is just not what I need, and I don't know the bst-language. The current output of the example below is an underlined journal name instead of an italic one.

I want the output as follows. Please note the italics journal name:

> Leal, T., E. Destruel und B. Hoot (2019). The Acquisition of Focus in L2
> Spanish. *Second Language Research* 35(4), S. 449–477.

Comment: Since you already tagged your question with `biblatex` you could try and switch to [biblatex-chicago](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago)

Comment: The most common causes for underline instead of italics is loading the `ulem` package. Just remove it if you don't need it. Load it as `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` if you absolutely must have it.

Comment: @DG': Thanks for your advice. I will take a look at it!

Comment: @moewe: That did the job! Thank you! The package was loaded, and I need it in a command, but the option did the trick. Now it looks as expected :)